Roche Geometry Visualization
I have a task in hand to create a Roche Geometry Visualization. All I am is a programmer and despite I have basic knowledge of math and algebra I am not match for what is awaiting me.
I have a fairly complex formula (https://comp-astrophys-cosmol.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40668-015-0008-8):
$$
\Omega(r, \theta, \phi) = \frac{1}{r} + q(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2rsin\theta cos\phi+r^2}} - r sin\theta cos\phi) + \frac{q + 1}{2} r^2 sin\theta^2
$$
To visualize the surface with the same potential I wish to calculate all the polar angles θ and the azimuthal angles φ.
So basically I have this $\Omega(r,\theta,\phi)$ and I need $r(\Omega, \theta, \phi)$. Is there a simple way to approximate it?

Indeed, my primary objective revolves around generating a visualization of Roche geometry for a binary star system (for reference, see: Roche lobe). I've explored Python modules that facilitate this task, such as those found in pyAstronomy and midnightkite.com. However, these modules typically operate in 2D or focus solely on calculating a single surface.

My aim is to develop a visualization capable of accommodating any given potential in a 3D environment. Any insights or suggestions on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.
